# How do I pass a variable from my View to my Controller?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I've generated a `<select>` dropdown menu on my view page with data from a stored procedure. Using JavaScript, I've accessed the selected `<option>` and saved the text into a variable. Now I need to send that variable back to my controller so I can use it as a parameter in another stored procedure.

Here is my Controller, titled "EventsController.cs"

```
    public ActionResult Dropdown(string text)
    {
        ViewData["ids"] = db.uspGetAllEventIds().ToArray();
        Console.WriteLine(text);
        return View();
    }
```

So you can see I run the 1st stored procedure and send it to the view.

Here's what happens in the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Heatmap.Models.Event>
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title></title>
    <script>
        function showValue()
        {
            var list = document.getElementById("EventId");
            var text = list.options[list.selectedIndex].text;
            alert(text);    
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("", "", FormMethod.Post))
        {
         <select id="EventId">
            @{
                var ids = ViewData["ids"] as string[];
                for (var i = 0; i < ids.Length; i++)
                {
                <option>@ids[i]</option>
                }
              }
         </select>
         <input name="text" type="submit" value="Submit" />
         <button onclick="showValue()">Click me!</button>
        }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So right now I have this alert function just to prove to myself that I have access to the `option` that I select. I'm pretty sure I need to use `FormMethod.Post` to get it back to the Controller, but I haven't been able to find any helpful references so far.

How do I format this so my variable `text` gets sent back into the controller?

Comment: Where is your action method in your controller for the POST?

Comment: @krillgar I had a separate one before posting but I deleted it to try and make my question more understandable. It was basically just an `ActionResult` function that I tried passing the data to without any luck

Comment: And how you have that Action method set up determines how to send the data to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to use jquery `$.getJSON` method to send and get variable from controller without refresh the page. I added .NetFiddle it works [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rcJeog)

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetDropdownList()
{
    var yourdata = db.uspGetAllEventIds().ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(text);
    return Json(new { data = yourdata}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Dropdown()
{
    // add your code here
}

//html
@using (Html.BeginForm("Dropdown","YourControllerName", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <select id="EventId" name="eventId">
    </select>           
    <input name="text" type="submit" value="Submit" />              
}
<button style="margin-top:20px;" id="yourid">Fill Dropdown!</button>

// jquery
$("#yourid").on("click", function(){
    showValue();
})

function showValue()
{
    $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetDropdownList", "YourControllerName")', function (result) {

        $("#EventId").html(""); // makes select null before filling process
        var data = result.data;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            $("#EventId").append("<option>"+ data[i] +"</option>")
            console.log(data[i])
        }

    })   
}
```

Comment: Are you putting the last section of code in the View?

Comment: you dont have to submit  your form to get value from controller

Comment: So I'll have to parse through the Json to generate a new select element, then the function should return the selected option to the controller?

Comment: This is also useful if you don't want to do a postback. But either you have to create a new route to match this getJSON url or use `Dropdown(int id)` since there is a matching route config for it. Also you have to add script reference to jquery and don't use 'Controller' word in the url.

Comment: I'm confused. This only posts the Json to my page, the `select` element never has a chance to be generated because showValue() cannot be accessed. I've even tried `<body onload="showValue()">` and no luck

Comment: I have updated my answer with working code using both the ways.

Comment: @LukeDangerKozorosky I have updated my answer with .NetFiddle link. it works there

Comment: @user8175473 looking at the code, we can't figure out what's going on with the submit button. Is `Ali` declared somewhere else in your controller?

Comment: @LukeDangerKozorosky last version : https://dotnetfiddle.net/rcJeog can you check it

Comment: @user8175473 Yes it looks like it works! Let me plug it into my code real quick and check it out

Comment: Yes thank you! Had to mess around with some of my filenames compared to yours which is why it took so long.

Answer (score 0):

A better way of doing it is you do a postback to your `Dropdown(...)` action on button click and change its signature to `Dropdown(string EventId)` which should give you selected EventId.

Here is the full code using both the methods.

```
public class EventsController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Dropdown()
        {
            ViewData["ids"] = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Dropdown(string eventId)
        {
            //call your sp instead of going back to the same page

            ViewData["ids"] = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Direct(int id)
        {
            //call your sp instead of going back to the same page

            ViewData["ids"] = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
            return View("Dropdown");
        }

    }

@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title></title>
    <script
              src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        function showValue() {
            var list = document.getElementById("EventId");
            var text = list.options[list.selectedIndex].text;
            $.getJSON('/Events/Direct/' + text, function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Dropdown", "Events", FormMethod.Post))
        {
         <select id="EventId" name="eventId">
            @{
                var ids = ViewData["ids"] as int[];
                for (var i = 0; i < ids.Length; i++)
                {
                <option>@ids[i]</option>
                }
              }
         </select>
         <button type="submit">Postback</button>
        }

        <button onclick="showValue()">Get JSON</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Should I call the postback in my JavaScript or simply in the `onClick`?

Comment: Ok I think we're getting somewhere with this. I'm about to take lunch, I'll look over more after. Hope you're still around by then but I may be posting back if I come across anything. Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: There seems to be a problem entering `ActionResult Dropdown(string eventId)`. I added `Console.WriteLine(eventId);` to the beginning and it never gets called

Comment: This code was tested and it worked. You should had put a break point in that method and tried. Anyway I guess you have found your solution.